# Laptop continues to work after lid is closed

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management

I have a Dell Precision 5550 laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 and kernel 5.4.0-104-generic. The laptop continues to work after the lid is closed, where it should go to suspend state, even automatically after 20 minutes when it's working on batteries.

When I put the laptop into the backpack it also becomes extremely hot.

Why does my laptop continue to work after closing the lid? How can I fix that?